# Parsing JSON array within an array in some nodes but not all

Tags: java, android, json

**I have a JSON Response with nested json arrays that I want to parse.**

Its a pretty straight forward JSON response but with one slight change in it.
The response I get is structured as a JSONarray with a small number of values in that array. In some of the elements, the value contains a nested JSONarray and has another set of data.

Now, parsing this JSON was pretty simple and I am able to get the data back in the right order.

**This is an example of the JSON (apologies if the formatting is incorrect - it is an example only):**

```
{
    "responseCode": "200",
    "responseMessage": "OK",
    "value_set": 
               [
                   {
                       "sample": "value",
                       "sample1": "value1",
                       "sample2": "value2",
                       "sample3": "value3",
                       "sample4": "value4",
                       "sample5": "value5"
                    },
                    {
                        "sample": "value",
                        "sample1": "value1",
                        "sample2": "value2",
                        "sample3": "value3",
                        "sample4": "value4",
                        "sample5": "value5"
                     },
                     {
                        "sample": "value",
                        "sample1": "value2",
                        "new_sample_data": 
                                         [
                                             {
                                                 "abc": "some_value",
                                                 "def": "some_value1",
                                                 "ghi": "some_value2",
                                                 "jkl": "some_value3",
                                                 "unique_data": "some_unique_value"
                                              },
                                         ],
                     },
                     {
                         "sample": "value",
                         "sample1": "value1",
                         "sample2": "value2",
                         "sample3": "value3",
                         "sample4": "value4",
                         "sample5": "value5"
                      },
                 ],
}
```

Now, to parse the whole thing, this is how I approached :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = responseObject.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("value_set"); 

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    if(object!=null){

    String sampleString = object.getString("sample");
    String sampleString1 = object.getString("sample1");

    //Till this point, the values are ok.    

}

}
```

The problem I have is with nodes that contain the `new_sample_data` array. I want to get the values of that particular node. I would have found that really easy if ***all*** the other nodes had that `new_sample_data` node.

However, as you can see, the values `sample<X>` are in every node but only some nodes (in the example, only one) have the additional data.

I think this can be solved by putting a couple of null check for the first node responses and then parse that particular array, but this is where I am stuck and any help would be really appreciated.

**Please don't recommend any libraries at this point.**

Comment: reason for down vote !! lol

Comment: you can place a check that if the JsonObject has length == 6, it means it does not contain array, else contain array

Comment: also a check for "{" and "[" .. But is there any other alternative way to do it more efficiently ?

Comment: Well, if you want to do it by your self, the only way is to place generic checks as you do not want to use library

Comment: let me write loop for this

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys.. lemme try it out!!

Comment: well .. voting down a question is still valid but if there was some comments on why, it would be great .. :/

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes were because the question seems quite broad.  Came to me in review queue for closing - I've tried to edit it to make it specific instead of voting as I think the question is reasonable.  have a look at the edits I made - they might help you avoid DV's in the future.

Comment: Got it.. thanks again.. edit seems good.

Answer (score 2):

Because `new_sample_data` `JSONArray` is not available in every JSONObject of `value_set` JSONArray.

Use [JSONObject.has()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)  and [JSONObject.isNull()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) to check if `new_sample_data` key is available or not in current JSONObject. if available then get all values from `new_sample_data` JSONArray in same way as currently doing for `value_set` JSONArray:

```
if(object.has("new_sample_data")){
            if(!object.isNull("new_sample_data")){
               // get JSONObject's from JSONArray
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using `has` method of `JSONObject`
E.g. :

```
if(object.has("new_sample_data")){
            //do something  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = responseObject.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("value_set"); 

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

if (object.length == 6){

    if(object!=null){

        String sampleString = object.getString("sample");
        String sampleString1 = object.getString("sample1");
        ....
    }

}
else{
    if(object!=null){

    String sampleString = object.getString("sample");
    String sampleString1 = object.getString("sample1");
    //parse array new_sample_data
    }

//Till this point, the values are ok.    

}

}
```

Comment: If the nodes were fixed, its gonna be hard to manage in future. Still +1.. this solution will work too

Answer (score 0):

If this format is fix then you have to put condition like

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = responseObject.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("value_set"); 

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    if(object!=null){

    String sampleString = object.getString("sample");
    String sampleString1 = object.getString("sample1");

if(i==2) {
JSONArray jsonArrayNewSampleData = responseObject.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("new_sample_data"); 
}
    //Till this point, the values are ok.    

}

}
```